# Keycloak custom themes

Tags: keycloak

I have Keycloak installed, and I would like to add custom themes for login, registration pages, and so on. My Keycloak version is keycloak-22.0.1.

My problem is that I don't know the best approach for this. Initially, I thought it might be suitable to use a Spring Boot project and then convert it into a JAR file. However, I'm not certain if this approach is intended solely for Keycloak X. So now, my question is: should I create a Spring Boot project and place it, along with all the custom HTML and CSS files, in a folder within the theme directory? Alternatively, should I convert it into a .jar file and then place it in the providers folder? Or am I mistaken, and does this work differently altogether?

Thank you!